# QCubed how to save QDateTime as NULL

Tags: php, mysql, qdatetime, qcubed

my QCubed PHP class "Project" has a property called "Finished" which is object of **QDateTime** and data type "datetime" in MySQL database. I need to **save NULL into database** when user leaves this field blank in HTML 
`<input type="datetime-local" name="Finished" />` 
but I cannot find a way for it since PHP always throws Internal Server Error 500

```
if ($_GET["Finished"] != "") $objProject->Finished = new QDateTime($_GET["Finished"]);
else $objProject->Finished = ???
```

Will be glad for any help.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer. Problem was somewhere else, my bad. You can simply do `$objProject->Finished = null;` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
$dataobject = new TableName();
$objProject->Finished = null;
$dataobject->Save();
```

Comment: example: if u want to save value into the table in qcubed u have to create its object first 
$dataobject = new TableName();  // creating the object of  `tablename`
$dataobject->Item = null;  // This will assign the value `null`. where `Item` should not be `not null` in the database.
$dataobject->Save();   // this shoud be written to save the data into the table